# WebSphere Commerce - How does ReLogonFormView / Session Expiration Work?

Tags: java, servlets, struts, websphere-6.1

Sorry for the broad topic.  Basically, WSC is supposed to have out-of-the-box session timeout handling by forwarding the user to the ReLogonFormView, which the user can presumably configure (through Struts) to any jsp that they choose.  We use a custom logoff command, and it seems to be affecting that view showing up.

I'm not looking for a specific solution to this problem, I'm just looking for general knowledge about how WSC (v6) handles session timeouts (how it determines that the session has timed out) and what command(s) it runs by default when / if / to determine the session has expired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my current knowledge on this subject...

The session timeout is a global value for all web modules and can be found in the wc-server.xml and is set to 30 minutes OOTB.

When a timout occurs, the OOTB LogoffCmd would normally be called, which will set up the necessary URLs to navigate to the ReLogonFormView URL while keeping hold of the URL where the session timeout occurred.
If the ReLogonFormView contains userid/password fields to allow the user to logon again, the user will then be redirected back to the page they were originally on.

More info can be found in IBM InfoCenter under "LoginTimeout".

If you extend the OOTB LogonCmdImpl, you should not try and set the forwarding URL, or that will interfere with the OOTB navigation.

I think you should perform your custom logoff functionality and then call super.performExecute() to allow the OOTB navigation logic to take over.
Note: You can retrieve the URL you were originally on via a call to getReferrerURL() and the ReLogonFormView should be returned from getURL().

Comment: And to change the 30 minutes is actually in: <Timeout display="false" value="1800000"/>. I read somewhere it was the combination of InactivityTimeout + Threshold in the ExpiryManagement section but it wasn't my case.